# Mysql query to check access to a private page

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Consider a group table and member-group relationship table as

```
CREATE TABLE group (
group_id int(11) not null auto_increment,
title varchar(50),
status ENUM('private', 'public'),
PRIMARY KEY(group_id)
);

CREATE TABLE group_map (
group_map_id int(11) not null auto_increment,
group_id int(11) REFERENCES group(group_id),
user_id int(11) REFERENCES user(user_id),
PRIMARY KEY(group_map_id)
);
```

Now in the group page, how can I show the content if

```
1. Group is public
```

OR

```
2. user is member of that group (user_id comes from $_SESSION login, 
and we check if the current group_id && user_id exists in group_map table).
```

Comment: I did this with two queries; first fetch status, then run second query depending on it: `WHERE group_id='XX'` OR `groups JOIN group_map USING(user_id)`. But I hope to do this in one single query.

Comment: You're missing commas after both `auto_increment`s.

Comment: @MattFenwick This is not the actual tables, I wrote here to show the structure. The actual tables are longer with comma of course ;) I corrected the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to retrieve a list of all groups that user `1` can access, complete with group name:

```
SELECT g.group_id, g.name
FROM `group` g
LEFT JOIN group_map gm
  ON gm.group_id = g.group_id
WHERE g.status = 'public'
  OR gm.user_id = 1
```

Here's an alternative, using `UNION`.

```
(SELECT g.group_id, g.name
FROM `group` g
WHERE g.status = 'public')
UNION
(SELECT g.group_id, g.name
FROM `group` g
JOIN group_map gm
  ON gm.group_id = g.group_id
WHERE gm.user_id = 1)
```

They them both out for size.

Notice the backticks around the `group` tablename because `GROUP` is a reserved word in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this...

```
SELECT g.*,gm.* FROM group g INNER JOIN group_map gm ON g.`group_id` = gm.`group_id`
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if I understand right what you want, you don't need 2-nd table. You can use Users table.

If group is private I was doin it that way

```
SELECT tblGroups.*, tblUsers.* 
FROM `tblGroups`, `tblUsers` 
WHERE tblGroups.id=tblUsers.group AND // here you put what you need to open //
```

otherwise group is public just this

```
SELECT tblGroups.* 
FROM `tblGroups` 
WHERE // here you put what you need to open //
```

Comment: 1. I need the second table for many-to-many relationship. 2. This method is what I am already using (quoted in comments). This needs an initial query to fetch the group status. I hope to do the whole process in one single query.

Comment: Ah! Ok then [this](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/many-to-many.html) may help